# angular2.js vs angular2.dev.js

Tags: javascript, angular

I was wondering about the differences between `angular2.js` and `angular2.dev.js`, of course there are more files like: `router.dev.js` and `router.js` and more, my question is why there are 2 versions and what is the differences between them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

angular2.dev.js uses `global.Zone.longStackTraceZone = require('../zones/long-stack-trace.js')` via zone.js for showing long stacktrace for angular exceptions to help with your development.

Source: https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.28/angular2.dev.js

Line 1984 to Line 2089

Comment: Thank you, now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually three versions of angular2.js along with three files for each dependency. There is the regular prod version of each (angular2.js), a minified prod version (angular2.min.js) and a development version (angular2.dev.js).  Check out this link to see how the files can be bundled: [Bundles, their content and usage scenarios](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/docs/bundles/overview.md)

Answer (score 1):

So as per @Bonneville's useful link the pattern would be, during development as "SystemJS loader user", to reference from the index.html the dev scripts:

- node_modules/angular2/angular2.dev.js,
- node_modules/angular2/router.dev.js and
- node_modules/angular2/http.dev.js

and then for production to swap in the minified scripts:

- node_modules/angular2/angular2.min.js,
- node_modules/angular2/router.min.js and
- node_modules/angular2/http.min.js