# What are the differences between the Angular 2 development bundle and the normal bundle?

Tags: angular

Angular 2 publishes to npm a series of bundles, for example the `angular2.js` and the corresponding `angular2.dev.js`.

The `dev` bundle is clearly meant for development mode, but what are the features that it contains to help development?

I think I heard in some talk that in development mode the bindings are checked twice? I think I read somewhere that its for improved stacktraces, which seems odd as in production we would benefit from those also.

is it safe/recommendable to use it in production.

What are the specific features that the development bundle contains over the normal bundle?

Comment: This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334662/angular2-js-vs-angular2-dev-js partly answers the question.

Comment: I think this issue may be useful https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3458