# angular2 from a CDN loads my page, but angular2 in my code's node_modules does not

Tags: angular

When I use the following CDN in my index.html to provide angular2, my page loads.

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.47/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

I have the same alpha.47 version in my code in the node_modules directory. That directory is directly below the angular2-oPost directory containing index.html. When I replace the CDN script with

```
<script src="./angular2-oPost/node_modules/angular2/angular2.js"></script>
```

the page no longer loads.

Console errors start with an error referring to angular2 code:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined    angular2.js: 4:1
http://localhost/angular2-oPost/angular2/angular2.js    404 not found
```

then there are many not founds  starting with  http://localhost/angular2-oPost/angular2/. . .

The reference error is in Google's code. The 404 says something is looking for angular2 in a directory that does not exist. Is angular2.js looking for something else. What should I change?

Comment: Those are not the same files, see that their contents are completely differents. The path is `node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js` (note the `bundles` addition).

Comment: Yes, bundles/angular2.js works.  I found that  bundles/angular2.dev.js  also loads the page.  Which should be used?  Does each have some specific purpose?  Put your comment in an answer, and I'll give you a green check mark.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Eric said you were pointing to the wrong file, you need to point to:

node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js

or

node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js

The purpose of them its obvious in the name itself, angular2.dev.js its meant to be used in development environment, and the other one for production.

I don't know all the exact differences between them though, I believe the main idea was to do less detail in the error logging but I have not noticed it myself yet, not that I have paid too much attention.

Also check: 
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3458 
- [angular2.js vs angular2.dev.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334662/angular2-js-vs-angular2-dev-js)

Looks like the proposal of what it "should" be, but the thing being in "beta" that looks like epsilon and all it might not be true, or at least not yet.